# Is it possible to move files around using django-filer?

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

This really isn't a programming question at all, just a question about features available in django-filer which I figure programmers who have used it will be able to answer.

Question is, is it possible to move files around (ie, from one directory to another) via the django-filer GUI?

Apologies for listing this under the django-filebrowser tag but I can't create new tags and the django-filer tag doesn't exist (plus I figure people who have used django-filebrowser might know about django-filer as well).

Answer (score 3):

Well this has been unanswered for a long time so I guess I'll answer it myself.

Yes, it is possible to move files around from one directory to another with django-filer. The mechanism employed to move files in django-filer is via the "clipboard". ie, you move files to a holding area on the right of screen called the clipboard, then you navigate to your desired destination folder and move the files off the clipboard and into the destination folder.